# If the law of a random variable $X$ is zero at a point, is then the density function of $X$ also zero at that point?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $X$ is a random variable s.t. $X[\Omega] = [-a, a), a > 0$ and that $X$ has a density function $f_X$. If we know that $\mathbb{P}_X(c) = 0$ for a fixed $c \in [-a, a)$ does it then follow that $f_X(c) = 0$?

I am aware of the fact that the probability of a continuous random variable being equal to any one point is zero. However, in a paper I am currently reading, it was proven quite extensively why $\mathbb{P}_X(c) = 0$ when $a = \pi, c = -\pi$, $X$ is a random variable in the unit circle and we are assuming that the variance is minimized at $\mu = 0$.

The paper in question and the specific portion are [Intrinsic Means on the Circle: Uniqueness, Locus and Asymptotics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2141) by Hotz and Huckerman, pp. 4 and 6; theorem 3.1 i.) and proposition 3.4.

The authors claim that the density of such a random variable $X$ in a certain setting is zero at $-\pi$, but IMO their paper doesn't explicitly argue why this is the case. Therefore, I'm interested in hearing whether $f_X(-\pi) = 0$ due to the setting of the authors, or because some known measure theoretic reason.

Comment: Did you read the paper? They assume $0$ minimises some function $V$ and found that for all small $\mu,$ $V(\mu) - V(0) \leq \mu^2 - c \mu \mathbf{P}_X(-\pi)$ and argue that the quadratic form is negative for small $\mu$ if $\mathbf{P}_X(-\pi) > 0,$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @WilliamM. I have read the paper up to the proof of proposition 3.4. While I do understand that there exists $S_1,\dots,S_k$ open arcs which either are distinct and disjoint (or can be made so) from the support of $\eta$, what I don't understand is how: "By hypothesis and virtue of Corollary 3.2 there is an open arc $S_1 \ni -\pi$...": that is, why is $f(-\pi) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}$?